# ¿Cómo cambio la el ícono del frame usando Java Swing? (No aparece la imagen)

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Intenté utilizar el imageIcon y unas cuantas variaciones, la imagen está en la misma carpeta y tiene el nombre que se muestra, sí, es en minúsculas. Todo swing está importado y aún así la imagen no aparece. Este es el código

```
    JFrame menu = new JFrame("Battle Pentagram");
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    menu.setLocation (300, 110);
    menu.setSize(900, 650);
    menu.setResizable(false);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("control.jpg");
    menu.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

Answer (score 2):

**setIconImage(Imagen image)** - pasarle ImageIcon = mala idea.

*Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(URL or file path);*

Toolkit es una clase del paquete awt que proporciona varios recursos y herramientas para el sistema de visualización.

Antes de llamar a getImage(), uno debe tener una referencia a la instancia de Toolkit en uso. El método estático devuelve una referencia a ese Kit de herramientas.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()

```
    JFrame menu = new JFrame("Battle Pentagram");
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    menu.setLocation (300, 110);
    menu.setSize(900, 650);
    menu.setResizable(false);
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("control.jpg");
    menu.setIconImage(image);
```

Comment: Las respuestas de solo código no son muy útiles, puesto que no explican cual es el problema, solo sirven para copiar y pegar y no *enseñan* nada. Por favor, añade la explicación a los cambios que has realizado para que la respuesta pueda ser útil a la máxima cantidad de gente posible :)

Comment: Gracias, ya añadí un pequeño comentario.